# How to have records based on by month and year

Tags: hive

From a source data like this:

| name | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 12-15-2022 | 01-05-2023 |
| Rick | 02-08-2023 | 04-02-2023 |

I am trying to have an output like this:

| name | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 12 | 2022 |
| John | 01 | 2023 |
| Rick | 02 | 2023 |
| Rick | 03 | 2023 |
| Rick | 04 | 2023 |

Where I am having records based on month and year. Is there any Hive function to do it directly?

Answer (score 2):

use `split` like this

```
select name, split(start_date,'-')[0] as mnth,split(start_date,'-')[2] as yr
union all
select name, split(end_date,'-')[0] as mnth,split(start_date,'-')[2] as yr
```

if you start_date are in date or timestamp format then you can use below functions.

```
month(start_date) as mnth_integer,
year(start_date) as year_integer
```

Pls note you may loose ,leading 0s in month value but logic will be same

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'John' name, '12-15-2022' start_date, '01-05-2023' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Rick' name, '02-08-2023' start_date, '04-02-2023' end_date
)
-- query starts here
SELECT name,
       (extract(year from start_date) * 12 + extract(month from start_date) + i - 1) % 12 + 1 AS month,
       floor((extract(year from start_date) * 12 + extract(month from start_date) + i - 1) / 12) AS year
  FROM (
    SELECT name,
           from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy')) start_date,
           from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(end_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy')) end_date
      FROM sample_table
  ) t lateral view posexplode(split(space(
      (extract(year from end_date) * 12 + extract(month from end_date)) - 
      (extract(year from start_date) * 12 + extract(month from start_date))), ' ')
  ) s as i, x
```

**Query results**

[image]